# Joint Laplace transform is product of Laplace transforms then independence

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, laplace-transform, expected-value, independence

I am stuck on a question from Chapter 2 Section 5 Question 21 of Erhan Cinlar's "Probability and Stochastics". This is the question:

> Let X and Y be positive random  variables. Then, X and Y are independent if and only if their joint Laplace transform is the product of their Laplace transforms, that is, if and only if $\mathbb{E}(e^{-pX-qY})=\mathbb{E}(e^{-pX})\mathbb{E}(e^{-qY})$, $p,q\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Show this recalling that the joint Laplace transforms determine the joint distributions.

I am working on independence$\implies\mathbb{E}(e^{-pX-qY})=\mathbb{E}(e^{-pX})\mathbb{E}(e^{-qY})$

I did not understand the hint. So I tried to use Stone-Weierstrass Theorem with sum exponential functions to approximate continuous function. And I managed to show that for any continuous functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$, $\mathbb{E}((f_X\circ X)(f_Y\circ Y))=\mathbb{E}(f_X\circ X)\mathbb{E}(f_Y\circ Y)$.

But to show independence we need $\mathbb{E}((f_X\circ X)(f_Y\circ Y))=\mathbb{E}(f_X\circ X)\mathbb{E}(f_Y\circ Y)$ for positive Borel functions, not just continuous. How may I continue from here?

Is there an easier way using the hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ and $\mu_{X,Y}$ are the probability measures induced by $X,Y$ and $(X,Y)$ respectively then the hypothesis says that the Laplace transform of the product measure $\mu_{X,Y}$ is same as the Laplace transform of $\mu_X \times \mu_Y$. This implies that $\mu_{X,Y}=\mu_X \times \mu_Y$ which is precisely what it means to say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: The hypothesis implies $\int_{E_X\times E_Y}\mu_{X,Y} e^{-pX-qY}=(\int_{E_X}\mu_X e^{-pX})(\int_{E_Y}\mu_Y e^{-qY})$, only for exponential function, and not for all $X-$ measurable, $Y-$measurable and $X,Y-$measurable function. So we cannot assume that $\mu_{X,Y}=\mu_X \times \mu_Y$?

Comment: @greenonion There is an inversion theorem for Laplace transforms. If two probability measures on $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ have the same Laplace transform then they are equal. This can be proved using Stone Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: Stone Weierstrass theorem is only for continuous functions. We need to show for borel measurable functions to show that the joint probability measure equals the product of the marginal probability distribution

Comment: It is basic fact that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures on $\mathbb R^{k}$ and  $\int f d\mu=\int f d\nu$ for all $f \in C_0(\mathbb R^{k})$ the $\mu =\nu$. @greenonion

Comment: Do you mean we should use $\int_{E_X\times E_Y}h d\pi=(\int_{E_X}f d\mu)(\int_{E_Y}g d\nu)=\int_{E_X}(\int_{E_Y}fg d\nu)d\mu$, where $fg=h$, therefore $\pi=\mu\nu$?

Comment: @greenonion SWT applied to the product space gives even  more: $\int F(x,y) d\pi (x,y)=\int \int F(x,y) d\mu \times \nu (x,y)$ for all $F \in C_0^{\infty} (E_X \times E_Y)$ not just for the special case $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.